# What are the uses and origins of the word 肌?

Tags: meaning, usage, kanji, etymology

Why is there a table radical in the word 肌? In what contexts is the word 肌 used?  Is 雪肌 an appropriate way to say fair skin?

Answer (score 6):

When you ask about etymology of a Japanese word written in *kanji*, you always have two (usually unrelated) stories.

1. The (Chinese) **character etymology** of the *kanji*, here 肌.
2. The etymology of the native Japanese word, here はだ.

---

1. The question about 几 appearing in 肌 is only about the first story about character etymology. In fact, 肌 is a 形声文字 *keisei moji*: the left-hand-side is the 肉 radical indicating "something-to-do-with-the-body", the right-hand-side 几 is merely used for its sound キ and has nothing to do with the meaning "table".
2. The etymology of the word はだ is unknown, but likely to be related to 端【はた】 or 果て【はて】 for the meaning of "end, bound, limit", the skin being the outer boundary of the physical body (see [gogen-allguide.com](http://gogen-allguide.com/ha/hada.html)).

---

<sub>For example sentences containing 肌, please take a look on [ALC](https://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%e8%82%8c).</sub>